# flash AS3 re-use instance

Tags: actionscript-3, instance, flash-cs6, isometric

I have been trying to make an isometric game in AS3. I am using a movieclip to stop the character from moving through objects like trees but i have to keep giving the movieclip a new instance name for every tree i use it for then add it into an array called barriersV.

what i'd like to do is just add one movieclip to the array and reuse it somehow, but as far as i know you cant use an instance name with more than one thing and only the most recent one will work. is there a better way to get the same result?

heres all my code:

```
var isRight:Boolean=false
var isLeft:Boolean=false
var isUp:Boolean=false
var isDown:Boolean=false
var isSpace:Boolean=false
var xspeed:Number=0
var yspeed:Number=0
var maxspeed:Number=9
var accel:Number=1
var sprites:Array = [];
var barriersV:Array = [];
var barriersH:Array = [];
var animationState:String = "idle";
var lastbtnpress:String = "none";

import flash.events.Event;
import flash.geom.Rectangle;
stage.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, cameraFollowCharacter);
function cameraFollowCharacter(evt:Event){
 root.scrollRect = new Rectangle(mc.x - stage.stageWidth/2, mc.y - stage.stageHeight/1.5, stage.stageWidth, stage.stageHeight);
}

stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, downKey);
function downKey(event:KeyboardEvent){
 if(event.keyCode==68){
 isRight=true
 isLeft=false
 mc.scaleX = +0.29;
 }
 if(event.keyCode==65){
 isLeft=true
 isRight=false
 mc.scaleX = -0.29;
 }
 if(event.keyCode==87){
 isUp=true}
 if(event.keyCode==83){
 isDown=true}
 if(event.keyCode==32){
 isSpace=true}
}

stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_UP, upKey);
function upKey(event:KeyboardEvent){
 if(event.keyCode==68){
 isRight=false}
 if(event.keyCode==65){
 isLeft=false}
 if(event.keyCode==87){
 isUp=false}
 if(event.keyCode==83){
 isDown=false}
 if(event.keyCode==32){
 isSpace=false}
}

stage.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, loop);
function loop(Event){
// if right is pressed and speed didnt hit the limit, increase speed
if(isRight==true && xspeed<maxspeed){xspeed+=4}
// if left is pressed and speed didnt hit the limit, increase speed (the other way)
if(isLeft==true && xspeed>-maxspeed){xspeed-=4}
// if speed is more than 0, decrease
if(xspeed>0){xspeed-=accel}
// if speed is less than 0, increase
if(xspeed<0){xspeed+=accel}

sortView()

// just like x, but with y
if(isDown==true && yspeed<maxspeed){yspeed+=4}
if(isUp==true && yspeed>-maxspeed){yspeed-=4}
if(yspeed>0){yspeed-=accel}
if(yspeed<0){yspeed+=accel}

// apply speed to movieclip
mc.x+=xspeed
mc.y+=yspeed


for(var i = 0; i < 500; i++)

    if ((mc.x < barriersH[i].x) && barriersH[i].hitTestObject(mc.mcBounds)){
        xspeed += 0;
        mc.x = mc.x-9;
    }
    else if ((mc.x > barriersH[i].x) && barriersH[i].hitTestObject(mc.mcBounds)){
        xspeed -= 0;
        mc.x = mc.x+9;
    }

for(var a = 0; a < 500; a++)
    if ((mc.y < barriersV[a].y) && barriersV[a].hitTestObject(mc.mcBounds)){
        yspeed += 0;
        mc.y = mc.y-9;
    }
    else if ((mc.y > barriersV[a].y) && barriersV[a].hitTestObject(mc.mcBounds)){
        yspeed -= 0;
        mc.y = mc.y+9;
    }

if(( isLeft == true || isRight == true || isUp == true || isDown == true || xspeed > accel || xspeed < accel *-1 || yspeed > accel|| yspeed < accel *-1)){
     animationState = "running";
}
if (isSpace == true){
    animationState = "jumping";
}
if(mc.currentLabel != animationState){
     mc.gotoAndStop(animationState);
}
if(( isLeft == false || isRight == false || isUp == false || isDown == false || xspeed == 0|| yspeed == 0)){
    animationState = "idle";
    }
}
for(var a = 0; a < 500; a++)
{
    var barrierV:Sprite = new Sprite();

    barrierV.x = Math.random() * stage.stageHeight;
    barrierV.y = Math.random() * stage.stageWidth;
    barrierV.graphics.lineStyle(2, 0);
    barrierV.graphics.beginFill(0xFF0000);
    barrierV.graphics.drawRect(0, 0, 50, 50);
    barrierV.graphics.endFill();

    barriersV.push( autumTree2V );
    barriersV.push( autumTree1V );
    barriersV.push( autumTree3V );
    barriersV.push( rockV );
}
for(var i = 0; i < 500; i++)
{
    var barrierH:Sprite = new Sprite();

    barrierH.x = Math.random() * stage.stageHeight;
    barrierH.y = Math.random() * stage.stageWidth;
    barrierH.graphics.lineStyle(2, 0);
    barrierH.graphics.beginFill(0xFF0000);
    barrierH.graphics.drawRect(0, 0, 50, 50);
    barrierH.graphics.endFill();

    barriersH.push( H1 );
}
for(var j = 0; j < 500; j++)
{
    var sprite:Sprite = new Sprite();

    sprite.x = Math.random() * stage.stageHeight;
    sprite.y = Math.random() * stage.stageWidth;
    sprite.graphics.lineStyle(2, 0);
    sprite.graphics.beginFill(0xFF0000);
    sprite.graphics.drawRect(0, 0, 50, 50);
    sprite.graphics.endFill();

    sprites.push( mc );
    sprites.push( grass );
    sprites.push( grass2 );
    sprites.push( grass3 );
    sprites.push( grass4 );
    sprites.push( rock );
    sprites.push( autumTree1 );
    sprites.push( autumTree2 );
    sprites.push( autumTreeRed1 );
}

function sortView():void
{
    // Sort the content of 'sprites'.
    sprites.sortOn("y", Array.NUMERIC);

        for each(var j in sprites)
    {
        // Then add each to the display list in the new order.
        addChild(j);
    }
}
```

Comment: Hmm. You say there is a number of trees on your game field, and you want all of them to act as barriers. This means you need a separate barrier object for each of them. I, however, see you pushing not a `barrierH` object into `barriersH` array, but a pre-placed instance `H1`, 500 times in a row. The same with both `barriersV` and `sprites` arrays - length of `sprites` will be not 10, but 5000! And then you will `addChild()` one of the objects 500 times in a row! Do rework this.

Comment: indeed, this code needs some serious refactoring :)

Comment: yea i sorta did alot of this code without a clue of what it does then left it and cameback months later with a slightley better idea of what im doing, so theres some code in there that i know i need to sort out but for now just ignore it.

Comment: what do i need to change to fix these problems? i dont know what "for(var j = 0; j < 500; j++)" does. is that what i need to change?